# Using datatables to display json file data

Tags: json, ajax, datatable, datatables

I tried many solution which are available in stack overflow but any single solution is not useful to me. Here is my code which I am trying still now.

> HTML

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Key</th>
     <th>Value</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

> Json file data

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    ....
}
```

> Datatables code

```
var table;
$(function () {     
    table = $('#example1').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax" : {
                "url" : "../apps/language/fr/fr.json",
                "dataSrc" : function (json) {
                    console.log(json ? json.length : 'json_data is null or undefined');

                    $.each(json, function( index, value ) {
                        
                        //console.log(index + "^_^" + value)
                        var html = "<tr>";
                            html += "<td>" + index + "</td>";
                            html += "<td>" + value + "</td>";
                            html += "<td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect waves-light edit'>EDIT</a></td>";
                            html += "</tr>";
                        var row = $(html);
                        $("#example1 tbody").append(row);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
});
```

Can you please help me where I am wrong? I need data in table format with pagination. Same like datatables. I already load databables library. I am also getting length error in js while I used this code. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: what does `json` show ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: did you tried [this](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax) way ?  Also , this error `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` is showing on which line ?

Comment: Yes @Swati. I tried this way. I have found solution in another way to fix this.